# How to debug WSO2 ESB code

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

How do you typically debug the ESB code? I am using log statements but they are kind of lost in system logs. Is there a better mechanism to be used?

Thanks,

Answer (score 16):

You can do remote debugging from your IDE with ESB code.

First start the ESB server script with debug option as follows.

```
wso2server.sh -debug 5005
```

where the number is any port number used for remote debugging from your IDE.

Then run debug in your IDE with whatever the port number you assigned.

Answer (score 5):

First, you have to setup debug configurations in your IDE which is can be learned using this [wso2 article](http://wso2.com/library/225/)

Then start the ESP server with debug option as follows.

```
<esb_home>/bin/wso2server.sh -debug 5005
```

After you start the server you will get this message:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

Then start debugging from your IDE!

[image]

This is the debug configuration I used:

[image: edit configurations]

Comment: IntelliJ Friendly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use eclipse IDE.
Start ESB using below command.

> wso2server.bat debug 8000 -Desb.debug=true

Setup eclipse remote java application.setup ESB server.

[image: Eclipse configuration]