# How to debug wso2 integration test source when we do maven clean install

Tags: maven, wso2

I needed to debug wso2 product integration test, In the integration test module pom file I found this line:

```
<argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</argLine>
```

I need to know the command that i need to replace it with to debug the mavan build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer! There are 2 ways of doing this,

**First way**

Should comment the below arg line which located in the pom file. You can include this in a parent pom file where you want to debug.

```
<argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</argLine>
```

and add below lines and configure the [debug configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255307/how-to-debug-wso2-esb-code/26418818#26418818).

```
<argLine>-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m
                        -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE
                        -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
                    </argLine>
```

Make sure you replace the address 5005 accordingly in [debug configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255307/how-to-debug-wso2-esb-code/26418818#26418818).

**Second way**

you can use `-Dmaven.surefire.debug` in command line rather using pom arg line which is the easiest way.

Then the build commend will be something like this>

> $ mvn clean install -Dmaven.surefire.debug

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to debug by passing `debug <port>` when starting wso2 products.

```
./wso2server.sh debug 5005
```